# Jupyter kernel to highlight syntax

Tags: jupyter-notebook, syntax-highlighting

I need to write lecture notes (about C++) and I want to use Jupyter Notebook.

Is there any simple kernel (or something else) to just highlight C++ syntax? I don't need to run code.

For now I use Markdown cells to write C++ code. I write code inside `<pre>` tags. There are two huge problems:

- no syntax highlighting;
- for example `vector<int>` is parsed as `vector` + `<unknown tag>` so the displayed result is `vector`. I have to workaround this by writing the following: `vector&lt;int>`. It's monotonous.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a Markdown cell type by specifying the language of a triple-backtick (```` ``` ````) code block. Change the cell type to Markdown, then make a code block like this:

````
```c++
while(true) {
  cout << "hello world forever" << endl;
}
```
````

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and you should see the cell rendered with code highlights.

[image]

Jupyter includes code highlighting via the Pygments module, so you can specify [any of the supported languages](http://pygments.org/languages/) in the code block.